# Avoiding the aliasing / thin "bleed between touching elements

Tags: svg, graphics, svg-animate

I have an svg which has multiple stroked paths, and a rectangle shape behind them that has the shape of the paths cut out of them. Effectively, the stroked paths should be "plugging the holes" in the rectangle shape.

The reason for this is that I would like to animate the paths so that they are erased, revealing what is underneath through the holes in the rectangle shape.

That's all well and good, and the animation works fine. The problem is that there is a hairline-thin space between the holes and the outside of the path strokes, so you can see what is underneath even while the paths are still there. You can see a screen capture of that here:

[image]

How do I avoid this happening? The space is not in the svg, because making it bigger on the page still has the space hairline thin:

[image]

I figure it has something to do with the aliasing, but have no idea how to combat it. I can't just apply a thicker stroke to the paths, because then the stroke starts to bleed into the other shapes, as seen here:

[image]

What else is there to do?

Comment: have you thought about using clip-path's? this would avoid the problem you're having - because they're designed for exactly this scenario.

Comment: @MichaelMullany I did consider it, but from what I could tell, there was no way to make the stroke of a path into a clipping path. And because of the animation, I need to keep the paths that are a single line with a stroke through each letter, as that's how the animation runs (through moving the stroke along the path). Would be happy to be proven wrong though! It seems what I  need is something akin to the Transparency Mask you can find in Adobe Illustrator, which essentially uses an alpha channel.

Comment: You could use a mask instead of a clip-path, that would allow using the stroke to define the masked area.

Comment: Here's an example of animating a mask that uses some stroked circles - http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/masking/mask-stroke-image.svg.

Comment: @ErikDahlström Ha! That's exactly what I was referring to, I had no idea there was an SVG equivalent. Thanks so much! If you want to post that an answer I'd be happy to mark it as the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [mask](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#Masking) instead of a [clip-path](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#ClipPathProperty), since masks allow using the stroke to define the masked area.

```
<mask id="strokemask" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" 
      x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
  <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.1" stroke="white" fill="white" 
          stroke-width="0.02"/>
  <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.15" stroke="white" fill="none" 
          stroke-width="0.03"/>
  <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.22" stroke="white" fill="none" 
          stroke-width="0.05"/>
  <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.3" stroke="white" fill="none" 
          stroke-width="0.06"/>
</mask>
```

Here's a [live example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/masking/mask-stroke-image.svg) of an animated mask that uses some stroked circles.